# How reliable is barcodedetector (Vision API)?

Tags: android, google-play-services, qr-code, google-vision, android-vision

I'm evaluating vision API to scan QR codes. I'm using Google's barcode-reader sample.  Detection of codes seem to work in most cases. However, I have come across a number of QR codes that the sample is unable to decode.  The same codes are easily decoded by zxing library on Android (e.g. Barcode Scanner app) or by apps on iPhone.

The problematic codes did not have quiet zones, or had the timing distorted due to scaling, or their images were mirrored (i.e. bitmap data origin was at bottom/left).

Is there a way to tune BarcodeDetector to be more tolerant?